# Listening for POLLIN on an fd in gevent

Tags: zeromq, gevent

I want to hook up ZeroMQ to the gevent loop. Using the ZeroMQ API, I can grab an fd for the socket. How do I watch this socket for POLLIN events in a greenlet, without blocking the other greenlets?

Answer (score 2):

Check out gevent-zeromq on github/pypi

Comment: Yep, checked it out, and thanks for authoring it! Unfortunately it doesn't fit my niche needs. I'll potentially have a great number of clients connected to my XREP socket at a time, many of which may block for extended periods of time. Thus I can't use the normal zmq approach of hooking up N worker sockets because it doesn't scale. My workaround is to listen for POLLIN on the XREP socket, receive the message, and handle it in a new greenlet. A single greenlet synchronizes reads/writes to the socket. AFAIK, I can't do anything like this in gevent-zeromq.

Comment: Sure, just have a single greenlet handling the socket comm and spawn on new message (and probably use a Queue for inter-greenlet comm).

Comment: The single greenlet has to handle both sending and receiving messages on the socket, because I don't think you can do both concurrently in zmq. I can't have it just recv() in a loop, because it will block while there are potentially messages to send. It needs to only recv() when it knows there is a readable message.

Answer (score 1):

```
# for gevent >= 1.0
hub = gevent.get_hub()
watcher = hub.loop.io(fd, 1)  # 1 = READ, 2 = WRITE, 3 = READ|WRITE
hub.wait(watcher)
# fd is now ready for reading
```

However it would be better to figure out how to use gevent-zeromq for this or extend it to support your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example from ZeroMQ. Request-reply broker http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:rrbroker
It listen for POLLIN event and with using gevent-zeromq will not block other threads.

Do this what are you was looking for?